# how to show the information, brought by nodejs, in html?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a unit management project, where I can add units and show units registered in my database,mongodb, following the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="./css/unidades.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Gerenciamento de Unidades - ChuteSal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-unidades">
            <div class="right-unidades">
                <div class="card-unidades">
                    <h1>Unidades Cadastradas</h1>
                    {{#each data}}
                        Name: {{name}}<br>
                        Address: {{address}}<br>
                        Quadras: {{quadras}}
                    {{/each}}
                </div>        
            </div>
            <form action="/unidades/register" method="POST">
            <div class="right-unidades">
                <div class="card-unidades">
                    <h1>Cadastre as Unidades</h1>
                    <div class="textfield">
                        <label for="name">Nome da Unidade</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtName" id="unidade" placeholder="Nome da Unidade">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textfield">
                        <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtAddress" id="endereco" placeholder="Endereço da Unidade">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textfield">
                        <label for="quadras">Quantidade de quadras</label>
                        <input type="number" name="txtQuadras" id="quadras" min="1" placeholder="Quantidade de Quadras">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn-unidades" type="submit" id="unidades-button">CRIAR</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my index.js

```
// config inicial
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// forma de ler JSON / middlewares
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  }),
)

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// rotas da API
// rota para Usuários
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/usersRoutes')
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);

// rota para Unidades
const unidadesRoutes = require('./routes/unidadesRoutes');
app.use('/unidades', unidadesRoutes)
```

And here is my unidadesRoutes.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const Unidades = require('../models/Unidades')

// criação de unidades
router.post('/register',  async (req, res) => {

    const Unidade = await new Unidades({
        name : req.body.txtName,
        address : req.body.txtAddress,
        quadras : req.body.txtQuadras
    })
    Unidade.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
  })

router.get('/dados', async(req, res) =>{
    try{
        const data1 = await Unidades.find({}, 'name address quadras -_id');
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Falha ao carregar os dados! '});
    }

})

module.exports = router
```

By postman, the route, "/unidades/dados" shows me the information I need, but I don't know how to show it in the html, how can I show this information?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use **javascript** and `fetch` to get this information. Like this.

```
<script>
   fetch("/unidades/dados")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
           // do what you want with that information
       }).catch((error) => {
           // error
       });
</script>
```